# Dynamically Setting Value With JQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I have a table of assignments.  Within each row is a cell, that when clicked will bring up a hidden div to the right of the table.  Within the div is a form that allows a user to associate a selected document with a task.

Currently the table is generated, in part, by a PHP "for" loop; I am cycling through an array and creating a new table row for each array index.

Within each row there are two table cells.  I want the contents of one of the cells to be a hyperlink that, when clicked, will display a hidden div.  Within the hidden div will be a form.  The form will have a hidden input box, and I would like to dynamically set this value when the hyperlink is clicked.

Here is a sample of the table:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Task</th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

  <?php
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($task_array); $i++)
    { ?>
      <tr>
         <td><?php echo $task_array[$i]['task'];?></td>
         <td><a href="#" id="show_div">Attach Doc</a></td>
      </tr>
    }
  ?>
</table>
```

Here is the hidden div and form:

```
<div id="hidden_div">
  <form action="[url]" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label for="file">Filename:</label>
  <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />           
  <input type="hidden" id="task_id" value="">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
</div>
```

I know that I can do the following with JQuery to display the hidden div:

```
$("#hiddendiv").show();
```

I also know that the hidden field 'task_id' can be set with JQuery by using

```
$("#task_id").val() = 'some value';
```

The problem I am having is that, since the values are coming from an array, I'm not sure how to specify a specific value.  For example, the value of a task id is found in the variable  $task_array[$i]['task_id'].  I could try this:

```
$('#show_div').click(function(){
     $("#hiddendiv").show();
             $("#task_id").val() = ???
});
```

I'm sort of stuck on specifying for which iteration to use the task id value.

My apologies if that wasn't very clear.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Comment: `$("#task_id").val() = 'some value';` isn't correct, if you want to set the value of the element use: `$("#task_id").val('some value');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP

```
  <?php
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($task_array); $i++)
    { ?>
      <tr data-task-id="<?php echo $task_array[$i]['task_id'];?>">
         <td><?php echo $task_array[$i]['task'];?></td>
         <td><a href="#" id="show_div">Attach Doc</a></td>
      </tr>
    }
  ?>
```

See that I added a `data-attribute` named `data-task-id` to the `tr` elements that stores the `task_id` for that row. We can use this in a `click` event handler later.

JS

```
//bind an event handler to the `tr` elements for the `click` event to show the `tr`s children elements (the `td`s)
$('tr').on('click', function () {
    $(this).children().show();

    //this next line is how we get the `task_id` associated with a row
    $(this).attr('data-task-id');
});

//since we bound an event handler to the `tr` elements for the `click` event it's a good idea to stop the propagation of click events on links within the `tr` elements so the event doesn't bubble up the the `tr` elements
$('tr').find('a').on('click', function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and in this case is the same as `.bind()`.

Also, you need to change the `#show_div` element's ID for each element (IDs **must** be unique). I recommend just changing it to a class instead of using an id:

```
<td><a href="#" class="show_div">Attach Doc</a></td>
```

Then you can bind an event handler to it like this:

```
$('.show_div').click(function(){
     $("#hiddendiv").show();
     $("#task_id").val($(this).parents('tr').eq(0).attr('data-task-id'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks!  I actually went the long way around and just made a function that accepts 2 parameters, and then added an onclick event to the attach doc link.  This is a more elegant solution.